# Find a small scale image into a large scale image

Tags: c#, image, pixel

I have images from two camera. Both of them send a picture but the picture of camera 1 is zoomed(Its like that picture of camera 1 is inside of picture of camera 2).

I have the position of a point in picture of camera 1. This position can change in different pictures. Now I want to find that point in picture of camera 2.

Both of cameras images are in 2560X2048 px.

How can I find that x,y in picture 2?

Comment: try [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). you would need java though. but it is powerfull, really easy and free.

Comment: i'm not sure that i get your aim truly,but if just you want find x,y in zoomed picture you can use coefficient of zooming too convert this values,please give more clues for more help dear friend

Comment: I have x,y of a point in zoomed picture now I want to find this x,y in unzoomed! picture. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I cropped the unzoomed! picture to be equal to zoomed picture. and save the x,y of cropped picture on unzoomed picture. Than I calculate percent of x,y of that point in zoomed picture. something like this :

```
double percentXZoom = (I_PLATE_MIN_X * 100) / 2560;
double xCropedImage = xD - xU;
double xDiff = (xCropedImage * percentXZoom) / 100;
double x = xD + Math.Abs(xDiff);

double percentYZoom = (I_PLATE_MIN_Y * 100) / 2560;
double yCropedImage = yD - yU;
double yDiff = (yCropedImage * percentYZoom) / 100;
double y = yD + Math.Abs(yDiff);
```

**"2560"** is the size of pixel in pictures.

**xD, yD** is the start point of cropped picture. and **xU, yU** is the end point of cropped picture.

Now I have the x,y of that point in unzoomed picture.